# SQL MAX() funct

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a list of workers in a table **Workers(ID, Name, Salary)**. 
If I want to see the name of a guy with a highest salary, I would do something like:

```
SELECT Name
FROM
(
SELECT Name, MAX(Salary)
FROM Workers
) as T
```

I was just wondering if I could do it using only one `SELECT` Query? I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but I'm completely new to `SQL`.

Comment: What kind of database? For SQL Server see: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/899812/get-any-hightest-value-in-table?arn=11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

more than 1 name with salary = max(salary)

```
SELECT top (1) with ties Name, Salary
FROM Workers
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Comment: Working nicely in mssql!

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough in the question, I want to select only the name of the highest paid worker, without his salary. If there are more workers with one highest salary is not important in my case.

Comment: So, if both Peter and John earn $50, what name would you like to return @ШонеДивљак ? A random of the two?

Comment: Doesn't matter, Peter or John or both.

Comment: @ШонеДивљак Ok, then your accepted answer (FuzzyTree's) is not the best answer (in my oppinion). Either "Top 1" or "limit 1" (depending on db) would serve you better.

Comment: Okay, I agree this may be better in general case

Answer (score 0):

Order by with a limit should work

```
SELECT Name, Salary
FROM Workers
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If there are multiple people tied for the highest salary, and you want them all:

```
SELECT Name, Salary
FROM Workers
WHERE Salary = (select max(Salary) from Workers)
```

Comment: what if there's more than 1 name with salary = max(salary) ?

Comment: Good point. Limit also works in postgresql. Here's a summary of ways to limit in other SQLs http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: now, you are using 2 SELECT statements ... original question wanted only a single SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

This will select all names with the max salary even if there are ties

```
select name from
workers w1
left join workers w2 on w2.salary > w1.salary
group by name
having count(w2.salary) = 0
```